# Old Flight numbers (2011)

Tags: air-travel

I am trying to find out a thomas cook flight number which was supposed to fly out of tenerife to UK (Manchester?) on friday 25th feb 2011 but did not go till saturday 26th.

Comment: Usually, but not always, the same flight number is used each day if the flight is at the same time. (Like a bus route has the same number each day.)

Comment: there is an aviation site in the stackexchange network. there it should go

Comment: @AndréPeseur Aviation.stackexchange is about the mechanics of aircraft, not, I think, the customer end of selling tickets and creating timetables

Comment: And this one is about travel and not,I think, about historical flight data

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend going into the historical index of [flightstats](http://www.flightstats.com/go/HistoricalFlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do), you will however need a free account.